# Android accelerometer and Android versions

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

since Android 3.0 the android.hardware.SensorManager.getRotationMatrix method result has to be remaped to work as on previous Android versions.

I use the next code:

```
android.hardware.SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(newm, null, mAccelerometerValues, mMagneticValues);
if( sdk >= 11){ //Honeycomb
            android.hardware.SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newm, 
                                                            android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y, 
                                                            android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_X, 
                                                            newm);
        }
```

Now, on Android Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) the SensorManager acts as on Android 2.X.
My question is:

The accelerometer is only rotated on Tablets? The accelerometer is only rotated on Android 3.X? If there any example of how to read the accelerometer in any Android version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some investigation I have found a solution:

Tablets have LANDSCAPE as default orientation, so screen rotation is 0 or 180 when the orientation is LANDSCAPE, and smartphones have PORTRAIT. I use the next code to difference between tablets and smartphones:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = getScreenOrientation(display);
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    remapCoordinates  = (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) ||
            (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) ||
            (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) ||
            (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT && rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270);
```

where getScreenOrientation method is:

```
public static int getScreenOrientation(Display display){


    int orientation;

    if(display.getWidth()==display.getHeight()){
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    }else{ //if widht is less than height than it is portrait
                if(display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()){
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                }else{ // if it is not any of the above it will defineitly be landscape
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                }
    }   
    return orientation;
}
```

Now, I remap the coordinates as before only when the default orientation is LANDSCAPE:

```
if( remapCoordinates){ 
            android.hardware.SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newm, 
                                                            android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y, 
                                                            android.hardware.SensorManager.AXIS_X, 
                                                            newm);
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: where I get this newm Variable in your last Codeblock? thank you